# SFML- Missing ';' before identifier

Tags: c++, sfml

I want Player to create an object of the class Bullet.
Result:

> syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'bullet'

From what i've can find about the issue is that the Bullet class isn't known to the compiler at that point,
 how do i make it known?

**Player class**

```
class Player :public Entity{

private:

    float velocity;

    Sprite titleSprite;
    Texture titleTexture;


    Sprite playerSprite;
    Texture playerTexture;

    Bullet bullet; // <-----------

public:

    virtual void draw(RenderTarget& target, RenderStates states)const;
    virtual void update(float dt);


    void movePlayer(float offset);

    Sprite getPlayerSprite()const;
    Sprite getTitleSprite()const;

    Bullet getBullet();

    Player();
    virtual ~Player();

};
```

**Bullet class**

```
#include "Player.h"


class Bullet : public Entity{
private:

    Sprite bulletSprite;
    Texture bulletTextucre;

public:

    void shootBullet(float offset);


    Sprite getBulletSprite()const;
    Sprite getBulletTexture();

    void setBulletSprite(Sprite bulletSprite);


    virtual void draw(RenderTarget& target, RenderStates states)const;
    virtual void update(float dt);


    Bullet();
    virtual ~Bullet();

};
```

Comment: It should be the other way: Include Bullet in Player, not Player in Bullet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Bullet class doesn't include Entity.h

Answer (score 0):

`#include Bullet.h` header inside the `Player` header file.

And remove `#include "Player.h"` from the `Bullet` header if you're not using anything from that class.

Comment: @mrewe: Then you have something else broken as well. Something you don't show here. And of course it should be `#include "Bullet.h"`, not `#include Bullet.h`